# How do I configure a Java EE maven project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, java-ee-6

I know Maven pretty well, but I usually work with Netbeans, which makes it quite easy to deploy Java EE applications - and handle hot deployment of any changes.

The team I work with now uses Eclipse as their IDE of choice, but none of them has worked with Maven projects before; so I need to know how to correctly add Eclipse's project facets to the maven projects we have, in order to support (hot) deployment through WTP. We are using Weblogic 12c for this particular endeavour.

Our project layout is as simple as it gets:

```
super-project (pom)
    project-ear (pom)
    project-ejb (pom)
    project-web (pom)
```

Thanks for any resource you can point me to.

Comment: m2e-wtp seems like what you need

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suppose that you've installed all required plugins to the Eclipse already. As @Michał Politowski mentions, [M2E](http://eclipse.org/m2e/), [M2E-WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/) and so on.

#### Add Archetype Catalog

1. Go to menu `Window--->Preferences`.
2. At the `Preferences window`, select `Maven---->Archetypes`,
3. On the `Right Panel`, click `Add Remote Catalog...` button.
4. At the `Remote Archetype Catalog windows` enter the following: -

   1. `Catalog file`: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   2. `Description` Maven Central
5. Add more remote catalog.

   1. `Catalog file`: http://download.java.net/maven/2
   2. `Description` Java.Net
6. Click `OK` to apply change.

#### Create the parent project

1. Go to menu `File ---> New ---> Other`.
2. At the `Select Wizard Windows`, select `Maven ---> Project`.
3. Click next and enter the required information so that we are at the `New Maven Project`.
4. At the `Filter` textbox, enter `pom`
5. Choose `org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:pom-root:1.1`
6. Click next and enter the required information so that the parent creation is finished.

#### Create the child project

1. Right click at the parent project and select `New ---> Other`.
2. 1. At the `Select Wizard Windows`, select `Maven ---> Project`.
3. Click next and enter the required information so that we are at the `New Maven Project`.
4. You will see that the `Parent Project` = `MY PARENT`
5. Enter the `Module name`, e.g. my-ear, my-ejb or my-web. Then click `Next` button,
6. At the `Filter` textbox, enter some of the following

   1. `org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:webapp-javaee6:1.5`
   2. `org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:ejb-javaee6:1.5`
   3. `org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:ear-javaee6:1.5`
7. Click next and enter the required information so that the child creation is finished.

#### Summary

I've used both NetBeans 7.x and Eclipse Juno together. When I move to Eclipse I've face the issue as same as your. Then I've captured the steps above from NetBeans logs one by one, and do the same thing manually by using Eclipse.

I hope this may help.

Comment: Shortcut for Maven command-line users: `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=ejb-javaee7`

Answer (score 6):

I would make one small change:

Create the child project

```
Right click at the parent project and select New ---> Other.
    At the Select Wizard Windows, select Maven ---> **Maven Module**
```

This way it will automatically recognize this as a child project of the parent.