# How to generate Java EE project structure via maven

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, dynamically-generated, archetypes

I'm new to maven, but I have worked on a project where there was a central pom.xml which included subprojects like dao, business and then web (controller, web). Is it possible to generate this kind of structure?

Comment: Please see [How do I configure a Java EE maven project in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683299/how-do-i-configure-a-java-ee-maven-project-in-eclipse/15696044#15696044)

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Maven Archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html). It depends what application you need, Maven has archetypes for both Java Web Application and Java EE application. So you need to run something like

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=basePackage -Dversion=1.0 
-DartifactId=projectName -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp     
-DinteractiveMode=false
```

Or you could use [JBoss Forge](http://forge.jboss.org/) - tutorial [here](http://forge.jboss.org/docs/using/basic-javaee-app.html). Forge will allow you to generate DAOs and web layer for entities, everything through CLI.