# Maven : ClassNotFound Exception in Web Application

Tags: maven

I have created a Web Application in Eclipse IDE using Maven Plugin as shown 
[image]

I have created a Servlet in that Project

The `pom.xml` generated is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>MTest</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MTest Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>MTest</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

**When i right clicked on pom.xml and executed Run as Maven Install**

I couldn't see the class file of my servlet under

```
C:\Users\sai\OfficeWSApril14\MTest\target\MTest\WEB-INF\classes
```

So as a result its throwing `ClassNotFoundException`

Please let me know what I was doing wrong

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MTest Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ MTest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ MTest ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ MTest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\sai\OfficeWSApril14\MTest\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MTest ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.1:test (default-test) @ MTest ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\sai\OfficeWSApril14\MTest\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ MTest ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [MTest] in [C:\Users\sai\OfficeWSApril14\MTest\target\MTest]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\sai\OfficeWSApril14\MTest\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [107 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\sai\OfficeWSApril14\MTest\target\MTest.war
[WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored 
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true')
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ MTest ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\sai\OfficeWSApril14\MTest\target\MTest.war to C:\Users\sai\.m2\repository\com\MTest\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\MTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\sai\OfficeWSApril14\MTest\pom.xml to C:\Users\sai\.m2\repository\com\MTest\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\MTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.536s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Apr 29 10:10:06 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ---------------------
```

---

When i right click on Eclipse IDE Project create new Servlet , how can i
ensure that the source file is placed under the src/main/java ??

I have attached a screen shot ,please see

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Maven` shows us as the following: -

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ MTest ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
```

This mean there is no any known java class. Please review your code and ensure that the source file is placed under the `src/main/java`

#### Edit

There are 2 possible ways to achieve your question about `how can i move the servelet under src/main/java ?`

1 Convert the existing `Maven Java Project` to be a `Dynamic Web Project` as the following steps: -

1. `Right click` at your project.
2. Select the `Properties` from the context menu.
3. At the `Properties Windows`  select `Project Facets`.
4. At the `right hand panel` please select the following: -

   1. Dynamic Web Module: 3.0
   2. Java: 1.6
   3. Java Script: 1.0
5. Click `OK button`

2 Create new `Maven Web Project` by using the following step: -

1. Go to menu `File ---> New ---> Other`.
2. At the `Select Wizard Windows`, select `Maven ---> Project`.
3. Click next and enter the required information so that we are at the `New Maven Project`.
4. At the `Filter` textbox, enter `webapp-javaee6`.
5. Select the `org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:webapp-javaee6:1.5`.
6. Click next and enter the required information so that the project creation is finished.

Please note, I would prefer the second way instead, since there will be the additional configuration at our `pom.xml` which is very useful for further development. You can also refer to my previous answer about the full story at [How do I configure a Java EE maven project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15696044/813999)

I hope this may help.

Comment: Thnks Charlee , i have edited my question , how can i move the servelet under src/main/java ??